# Difficulty displayling custom error message using PEAR PHP

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, pear

I need help displaying a custom error message when my search query returns `MDB2 Error: no such field`. 
I can't figure how to do this in my program. 
Any help will be highly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try these

http://pear.activeventure.com/core/core.pear.pear.seterrorhandling.html

http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.db.db-error.php